# https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx shows blank page

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have one single user who is trying to access our SharePoint Online Intranet site.  However, the user just receives a blank page.

For example, if they navigate to `https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx`, they receive a blank page, with a few JavaScript errors reported.

> Object doesn't support this action
>   sharepointhome-5a54066c.js  Line 1
>
> Object doesn't support this action
>   sharepointhome-5a54066c.js  Line 5
>   URI: https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sphome-next-prod_ship-2016-06-20_20160620.001/sharepo...
>   `

Comment: Is it for a single user or all users ?  What browser the user is using ? Does the site is being blocked by any firewall ?  Can you check if the user is able to access site from open internet ?

Comment: What browser version? Do they also have trouble with libraries using the new library experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered that this user was still on Internet Explorer 8.  As of 12th January 2016, this browser version is apparently "unusuable" with Office Online.

Reference: https://products.office.com/en-AU/office-system-requirements/#Browsers-section